# Merge two dataframe where rows have no exact match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I merge two dataframe in pandas where one column contains only starting letters of matching rows?

For example, I would like to merge df1 with df3. ("*" is replacing any characters like in excel

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['B0204040*', 'AZS12*'],
                    'value': [1, 3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['B0204040AL-5W', 'B0204040AL-7.5W', 'AZS12AD4-5S', 'AZS12-AS']})
```

and get df3

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['B0204040AL-5W', 'B0204040AL-7.5W', 'AZS12AD4-5S', 'AZS12-AS']})
                    'value': [1, 1, 3, 3]})
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case ('*' in the end), you could use a regex to find the matches:

```
import re
s1 = df1['lkey'].str.rstrip('*')
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, s1))
# 'B0204040|AZS12'

s2 = df2['rkey'].str.extract(f'({regex})', expand=False)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on=s1, right_on=s2).drop(columns='key_0')
```

output:

```
        lkey  value             rkey
0  B0204040*      1    B0204040AL-5W
1  B0204040*      1  B0204040AL-7.5W
2     AZS12*      3      AZS12AD4-5S
3     AZS12*      3         AZS12-AS
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to iterate over `df1` rows and check if `df2` `rkey` column matches the `lkey` column.

```py
df2['value'] = pd.NaT
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    df2['value'] = df2['value'].mask(df2['rkey'].str.match(row['lkey']), row['value'])
```

```
print(df2)

              rkey value
0    B0204040AL-5W     1
1  B0204040AL-7.5W     1
2      AZS12AD4-5S     3
3         AZS12-AS     3
```